# How do you determine the derivative of $\pi$?

Tags: calculus

> If $y=\pi^2$, then $dy/dx=2\pi$
>
> Is this statement true or false? If false, correct the statement.

My answer to this question is false because $y=\pi^2$, there is no variable.

I like to know if my answer is correct, and I would appreciate explanation.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The derivative of any constant function is $0$.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct: the statement is false. Since $\pi^2$ is a constant, its derivative with respect to $x$ is $0$. This is no different in principle from the fact that if $y=4=2^2$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$.

The statement illustrates a failure to apply the chain rule: a corrected version would be

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\pi^2\right)=2\pi\cdot\frac{d\pi}{dx}=2\pi\cdot 0=0\;.$$

Of course this is doing far more work than is necessary, since we can recognize immediately that $\pi^2$ itself is already a constant and therefore has derivative $0$.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of any constant is zero. If $\pi$ is a variable, then $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$, because $y=\pi^2$ is not a function of $x$.

Comment: it has nothing to do with whether or not $\pi$ is a variable

Comment: Sure it does. The value is the same, but one must make a distinction between differentiating with respect to a constant, and with respect to a different variable not appearing in the function. $\frac{d}{dy}e^x = 0$, but $e^x$ is not a constant if $x$ is a variable.